# Angular Library Project - how to build and use a library with own dependencies (not peerDependencies)?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have created an Angular Library Project, and a simple application next to it where i show the usage of it. The structure looks like this:

[image]

This is how it looks in the library's package.json:

[image]

"@angular/cdk" is used in a component in the library, where i have an import like this:

```
import { LiveAnnouncer } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
```

Everything is fine until now. Now when i want to run my demo application (ui-components-showcase) which imports (in its app.module) the library directly from the folder structure (without actually building the library itself), everything works as it should be.

But when i want to do it in the correct way, by building the library first (ng build ui-components), and importing the build lib folder in app.module, by starting the server with i get this error:

[image]

And this is actually how app.module looks in webstorm:

[image]

When i open the component.d.ts file in the dist folder, i see the error also in the place where i import the LiveAnnouncer from @angular/cdk/a11y. So the dependency is really not there in the build lib.

What is going on here and how can i fix it?
I appreciate for any help.

**Edit**: this is how it looks again with 2 node_modules folders. 1 is for the library itself, the other one in the root is for the whole library project incl. sample app (showcase). This is created by angular/cli, did not make any structural changes. The root package.json which is seen here, is also as created from angular/cli, did not change anything there. And since the dependency angular/CDK is just needed from the library itself, i just included it in the inner package.json of the library itself, as it should be. The showcase itself does not have any CDK dependency.

[image]

Comment: Show your ui-components-showcase package.json, did you import your library here and did `npm i`?

Comment: showcase does not have its own package.json, and should not have also. The whole workspace has its own package.json, that is what u mean probably.. I will paste a screenshot of it. The @angular/cdk library is imported to library's package.json as stated above. npm i is of course executed, otherwise the library would not work at all. As also stated above, the library works when i import its folder direclty

Answer (score 0):

Usually the showcase would be an `application` project in the same Angular workspace as the `library` project, with both sharing `node_modules`

Here's an example (picked at random) of an Angular npm component library, with the showcase/demo app as part of the same repo (the same Angular CLI workspace)

- https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-color-picker/tree/master/projects

Comment: The showcase is an application in the same workspace, but they are not sharing (and do not have to by default) the same node_modules. I will paste a screenshot of project structure again

Comment: The github project you wrote does not seem to have the latest expected angular changes .. the newest cli generates an inner package.json with both "peerDependencies" and "dependencies" sections, where the dependencies have also at least one default dependency "tslib".